# How to create pointers Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unreal-engine4, null-pointer

In the blueprintable class I define the pointer at `FJsonValue`.

```
private:
    TSharedPtr<FJsonValue, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> JsonValue;
```

After calling the method that allocates memory, I got the null object...

```
void UDictValue::SetInt(float value)
{
    ValueType = EDictValueType::VT_INT;
    JsonValue = MakeShareable(new FJsonValueNumber(value));
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, "test");
}
```

`MakeShareable` in fact allocates new memory. Debugger says about the address where that was allocated... But after returning from function, pointer drops immediately (`JsonValue = NULL`)

Whats wrong? Is this GC? But I need this pointer after calling of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the object inside the function and using `MakeShareable` to assign it to the `TSharedPtr`.  As soon as the function goes out of scope, the created object is destroyed nulling the `TSharedPtr`. To get it to stay persistent, you will have to create the object outside the function, and then point the `TSharedPointer` at it.

What you should probably do is just initialize it at object level, and then just change the value with your function, rather than trying to create it inside the function.

MakeShareable just makes it possible to explicitly convert from a C++ style pointer to a TSharedPtr it doesn't actually change how the TSharedPtr behaves.